# Como selecionar na tabela de usuário os usuários que estejam com o campo STATUS =1?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada USUARIOS com os campos NOME, STATUS. Suponhamos que eu tenha 10 usuários cadastrados.

Como eu posso checar se os 10 usuários possuem o STATUS = 1 e caso afirmativo, exibe na tela um (OK).

Eu sei que tem que fazer um SELECT, até aqui tranquilo, mas qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso sem usar `array` ou `loop`?

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria selecionar todos os usuários com o valor `1` na coluna `STATUS` e fazer a contagem dos mesmos.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","utilizador","password","base_dados");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Erro na coneção á BDL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Executa a query
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status FROM usuarios where status = 1;");

$n_utilizadores = mysqli_affected_rows($con);

echo "Existem " . $n_utilizadores. " com STATUS = 1";

if ($n_utilizadores == 10)
{
    echo "OK";
}
```

Poderá também inverter a query e perguntar á BD se existe algum utilizador com o campo `STATUS = 0`, caso exista 1 ou mais retorna `erro` caso contrário retorna `OK`

Answer (score -6):

Bom cara acho que pra fazer isso a melhor forma é usar um loop com `foreach`, onde te trara todas as informações buscadas no banco com o select permitindo com que você consiga manipular os dados da melhor forma que te agrade.

//Exemplo da variável que armazena sua busca com o select

```
  $armezanaValoresDoSelect= "sua busca no banco";

    foreach($armazenaValoresDoSelect as $NewValues){
         //faça uma validação onde se a $NewValues['status'] == 1 echo "ok";
    }
```

O foreach fará um loop enquanto houver dados a ser manipulados. Este é o melhor jeito que eu conheço para manipular dados de bancos, gerando loopings. Espero ter a ajudado!

Answer (score -9):

`foreach` é uma boa opção, sem loop não será possível, a não ser que esteja usando Bootstrap, daí talvez hajam outras opções.

Comment: Eu quero fazer algo assim: Se exibir 10 registros retornados pelos SELECT, verifica se os 10 possuem o 1 no campo STATUS, existe algum exemplo ?

Comment: Cara se você não usa bootstrap vai ter que ser por loop. Vou fazer um exemplo em for.
Coloca tudo num array e faz o for, impossível outra maneira.

Comment: Pensei aqui, como você tem várias informações para cada usuário, cada usuário tem que ser um array dentro de um array mãe, vai ficar bem confuso amigo.

Comment: @MatheusCardozo o campo resposta é para uma resposta válida, para dicas pode usar o campo de comentários, você ainda pode editar sua resposta e colocar um exemplo... Evita negativos...Gl ;)

Comment: @MatheusCardozo O que o bootstrap tem a ver com o problema dele? Da uma revisada nisso ai man..